# What file(s) (on GitHub) should have the copyright owner's name for GPL3?

Tags: gpl-3, license-notice, software-use

Lots of projects on GitHub have a GPL3 License, as it's easily created by their software when you want to add a license and you choose GPL3. However, unlike the MIT license, you don't put your own name in the license. Furthermore, the GPL3 license text says you can't modify it:

> Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc. https://fsf.org/ Everyone is permitted to copy and distribute verbatim copies of this license document, but changing it is not allowed.

I understand the reasons this file can't be modified.

However, where should one put in a GitHub repo the information that you can find in an MIT license, e.g., the copyright that belongs to the person who created the work?

The FSF has the following [FAQ and answer](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.en.html#IWantCredit):

> I want to get credit for my work. I want people to know what I wrote. Can I still get credit if I use the GPL? (#IWantCredit)

> You can certainly get credit for the work. Part of releasing a program under the GPL is writing a copyright notice in your own name (assuming you are the copyright holder). The GPL requires all copies to carry an appropriate copyright notice.

GitHub's "add a license" feature doesn't cover this dimension of GPL. How is this done properly. Is it a "Copyright" file that's separate? Are there examples of GitHub repos where this has been done?

My reason for asking is I want to reuse a GPL3 repo and give credit to the original author. However, their own repo doesn't have their copyright info (and I think it's pretty common with GPL3 on GitHub).

My question is related, but significantly different from [GPL and original author's copyright text in completely rewritten code](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/11898/12766), because the answer there doesn't explain where the copyright info is stored (in each source file, in a LICENSE.md, etc.)

Comment: Have a look at the appendix at the end of the GPL license text, "How to Apply These Terms to Your New Programs"

Comment: I posted an answer below that is basically a copy of an answer on the software engineering stack exchange.

Answer (score 2):

You have to put the copyright at the start of each source file, according to the answer at https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/281951/51948

> Here's the correct way to apply the license:
>
> 1. In *every* source code file, insert the following in a comment (fill in `*program name*` and `*your name*` and `*years*`):
>
>    ```
>     This file is part of *program name*.
>     Copyright (C) *years* *your name*
>
>     *program name* is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
>     it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
>     the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
>     (at your option) any later version.
>
>     This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
>     but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
>     MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
>     GNU General Public License for more details.
>
>     You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
>     along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
>    ```
> 2. Put a file called `LICENSING` or `COPYING` or something like that in the root of the project folder. Put the *entire* GPL
>    ([here](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.txt) is the official text) in
>    that file. The file must contain the verbatim GPL; do not change it in
>    any way.

Comment: For the files of the original author that were missing the notice: did you add in the missing notice (with the original author's) in your copy?

Comment: @Brandin no, but I only reused one of the original files, and under my notice I put a url to the original file.